# Python: os.walk usage for scanning specified directory and search specified file issue

Tags: python-3.x, os.walk

I want to scan current and deeper folder to search specified file.

[~/test]$tree -a
[image: Test background]

Upon is my test environment.

[~/test]$ls

```
NCRAM955E/  RNCMST954E/  RNCMST957E/  test.py*
```

Below is my code:

```
import os, shutil, sys, getopt, re

def GetOption(argv):

    FileDir = ""
    Roptarget = ""
    Dirtarget=[]
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hD:F:",["FileDir=", "Roptarget="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print ('Error arg input -D <FileDir> -F <Roptarget>')
        sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == "-h":
            print ('Error arg input -D <FileDir> -F <Roptarget>')
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-D", "--FileDir"):
            FileDir = arg
            Dirtarget = FileDir.split("|")
        elif opt in ("-F", "--Roptarget"):
            Roptarget = arg
    return(Dirtarget, Roptarget)

#Below self defined function need update
def detect_walk(file_dir):
    L_0 = []
    L = []
    DirList,Ropfile = GetOption(sys.argv[1:])
    print("DirList = " + str(DirList))
    print("Ropfile = " + Ropfile)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_dir):
        for file in files:
        L_0.append(file)
        if " ".join(L_0).find(Ropfile):
            print("target rop file = " + Ropfile)
            L.append(os.path.join(root, Ropfile))
    return(L)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_path = "/home/test/"
    List = detect_walk(file_path)
```

My expect output, for exapmle

if I type `python test.py -D "RNCRAM955E|RNCMST954E" -F "^A20180520.1300+0300-1315+0300*RNCMST954E_statsfile.xml$"`

the program will only search foler `RNCRAM955E` and `RNCMST954E`, when specified file match pattern found , it will display the full-path of the target file.

i am python freshers. please give me some advice. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have update my code, this code will enable transform specified file which in specified folder to another folder.
Use like `python temp.py -D "RNCMST954E|RNCMST957E|RNCRAM955E" -F "A20180520\.13*"`， but some codes remain improve, as you see, the filename after `-F` should add escape symbol `\` . So, how can I improve this ?

```
import os, shutil, sys, getopt, re

def GetOption(argv):

    FileDir = ""
    Roptarget = ""
    Dirtarget=[]
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hD:F:",["FileDir=", "Roptarget="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print ('Error arg input -D <FileDir> -F <Roptarget>')
        sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == "-h":
            print ('Error arg input -D <FileDir> -F <Roptarget>')
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-D", "--FileDir"):
            FileDir = arg
            Dirtarget = FileDir.split("|")
        elif opt in ("-F", "--Roptarget"):
            Roptarget = arg
    return(Dirtarget, Roptarget)


def detect_walk(file_dir):
    L = []
    desdir = "/home/ekoopgj/ITK/Task/test_folder/"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_dir):
        for file in files:
            if re.search(fileIndex,file) is not None:
                L.append(os.path.join(root, file))
                print("start copy " + os.path.join(root, file) + " to " + desdir)
                shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(root, file),desdir + file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DirList,fileIndex = GetOption(sys.argv[1:])
    #use LOOP For and store the file_path varibale as a Formal parameters , can reduce the search time if the target folder contains too many files.
    for dir in DirList:
        file_path = "/home/ekoopgj/ITK/Task/0521/"
        file_path += dir
        print("dir = " + dir)
        List = detect_walk(file_path)
```